# CSS/Styling Advice

Tags: css

I am trying to make this look not so childish. I was wondering if someone could give me some pointers on making this look a little more professional. What I am trying to do is just section these three sections. But this just looks like my 2 year old son created it. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/7hffq081/

```
.mobilehomelabel {
    color: red;
}

.test {
    outline:1px solid red;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include the html as well?

Comment: @KTE this would be more appropriate in Graphic Design

Comment: Well, I don't mean any offense. It's just a comment but that's the reason some of us can make a leaving at graphic designers. My advise if you are a new to it... you have some lists, surf around (many hours) till you find something simillar to what you would like... then try to adapt it and modifie it with what you think could be better. With time (in my case many years) you won't "modifie" anything and you will take your own ideas into play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try improving the layout with margins for your inner divs, and making the header text larger than the sub-text. You can also apply different color to make it stand out, and create different colors for odd/even rows to differentiate them. Add border-radius for extra polish. For super fancy polish, add hover for your sub rows and box shadow for your wrapper.

```css
.test {
    border:3px solid black;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.test div {
    padding:15px;
}

.mobilehomelabel {
    color: black !important;
    padding:20px !important;
    background-color:rgba(110,234,139,0.6);
    font-weight:500;
    font-size:1.5em;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
}

.sub {
    color:white;
    background-color:rgba(190,20,20,1);
}
.sub:nth-child(odd) {
    color:white;
    background-color:rgba(100,180,200,1);
}
.sub:last-child {
  
    border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
}

.sub:hover {
  color:black;
  background-color:rgba(210,215,211,0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>
    <div class='mobilehomelabel'>Home 1</div>
    <div class='sub'>Words</div>
    <div class='sub'>Words</div>
    <div class='sub'>Words</div>
    <div class='sub'>Words</div>
</div>
```

The styles used are throw-aways, especially the colors. Consider researching sites and examining the styles they use.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a slight change in the theme of what you have done

http://jsfiddle.net/7hffq081/2/

```
<div class="mobilehomelabel">Mobile Home 1</div>
```

And the css that changed

```
.mobilehomelabel {
color: red;
padding-bottom:3px;
margin-bottom:5px;
width:100%;
border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
.test {
border:1px solid red;
border-radius:2px;
padding:5px;
}
```